# Accessing Java packages and classes in JSP file

Tags: java, jsp

I am currently trying to create a JSP page that can access Java classes as a practice. I have a simple JSP page called index.jsp which accesses my User.java class in business package like so:

```
//index.jsp
<% page import="business.*"
```

As I try to run the the project, I get this error:

```
Generated servlet error:
bad class file:
..\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Demo\WEB-
INF\classes\business\User.class
class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 48.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
import business.User;
```

Initially, I had the package stored in my src folder and so I tried moving it to the classes folder under WEB-INF as specified on that error. I've also tried restarting my workspace thinking that the change in the paths that I've made wasn't detected but the same error persists. Why am I getting this error? Please advise.

Also, I'm still a beginner with Java, using JSP and accessing classes from packages using button press. Are there any good tutorials/demo for this that you can recommend?

Comment: 48.0, that's Java 1.4.  What prehistoric server are you using?

Comment: Yes I know but there's an existing project that I'll be joining soon that runs on Java 1.4 so my Eclipse' setup is for 1.4

Comment: Not quite, the class got generated in JDK7 format (51.0) - not an Eclipse user myself, but there should be a setting somewhere that forces compilation of classes to be compatible with older JDK's...

Comment: Yes, I've already set it to compile for 1.4. It runs fine without the import but that's the whole point of creating the test project.

Comment: Wait, I've read your comment again. That might be the case. I'll double check. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting Compiler to 1.4 is fine. Check the java environment in

Right click on project -> Configure Build path -> Java library

Make sure that library is 1.4. If it is not, change it to 1.4. Close the eclipse and start it again. (Don't restart)